# Display Contacts List using Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to display Contact List using Fragment,

I download sample from here [contact_picker](https://github.com/codinguser/android_contact_picker)

In this sample they use ListFragment, I have change it to Fragment and all other necessory changes then I run the application but it doesn't show the contact list, how can I done it with Fragment

**Edited:**

I just Changed in below tow files

ContactsListFragment.java

```
package com.codinguser.android.contactpicker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AlphabetIndexer;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SectionIndexer;

public class ContactsListFragment extends Fragment implements 
LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

private OnContactSelectedListener mContactsListener;
private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
private String mCurrentFilter = null;

ListView listView;

String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

private static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        Contacts._ID, 
        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, 
        Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
        Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts_list, container, false); 
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list); 
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    mAdapter = new IndexedListAdapter(
            this.getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item_contacts,
            null,
            new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
            new int[] {R.id.display_name});

    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {           
        mContactsListener = (OnContactSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnContactSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    Uri baseUri;

    if (mCurrentFilter != null) {
        baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(mCurrentFilter));
    } else {
        baseUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    }

    String selection = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
            + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
            + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";

    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    Log.v(TAG, "Name = "+ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, selection, null, sortOrder);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}

class IndexedListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer{

    AlphabetIndexer alphaIndexer;

    public IndexedListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, 0);     
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor c) {
        if (c != null) {
            alphaIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(c,
                    c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME),
                    " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
            Log.v(TAG, "data = "+ c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
        return super.swapCursor(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        return alphaIndexer.getPositionForSection(section);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return alphaIndexer.getSectionForPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        return alphaIndexer == null ? null : alphaIndexer.getSections();
    }
}
}
```

fragment_contacts_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Nothing to see here!"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you run the project in emulator or device?

Comment: I tested it on both, device and emulator also, but it doesn't display Contact List

Comment: does it print any error in your log cat?it is better to work in device that emulator doesn't have contact list.